# Bootstrap HTML form, not responsive

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive

I have created an html form using bootstrap columns to get the desired layout. It's about where I want it for desktop but it piles together on mobile. I don't believe any of the code I've used is working with bootstrap. Here is the form itself:

```
    <div class="center_div">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <h3>First Name</h3>
                <input name="fName" type="text" />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <h3>Last Name</h3>
                <input name="lName" type="text" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <h3>Company Name</h3>
                <input name="compName" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>Business Type</h3>
            <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="businessNeeds">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="IntDesign">Interior Designer</option>
                <option value="Ecom">E-Commerce Only</option>
                <option value="Retail">Retail Store Only</option>
                <option value="RetailEcom">Retail and E-Commerce</option>
                <option value="Mult">Multiple Locations</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="input-group input-group-xs">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="address" type="text" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>City</h3>
            <input name="city" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
            <h3>State</h3>
            <select name="state">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                /*Took out states for space*/
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <h3>Zip</h3>
            <input name="zip" type="text" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>Phone</h3>
            <input name="phone" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>Email</h3>
            <input id="email" name="uemail" type="text" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <h3>Create a Username</h3>
            <input name="uname" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <h3>Create a Password</h3>
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="pass" type="password" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="ConfPass" type="password" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>Sales Tax ID</h3>
            <input name="taxID" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <h3>Upload Tax ID Certificate</h3>
            <input name="fileUpload" type="file" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The CSS:

```
.center_div{
    padding-left:150px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .mainForm{

}

.center_div{

    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
}

.center_div label{
    width:100%;
    float: none;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
```

.mainForm is a blank div around the form, there is nothing else on the page. I left the CSS pretty barebones but is there a fairly simple way to make this respond better on mobile with bootstrap? Even if all the fields just sat on top of one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your bootstrap rows must be inside a .container div, otherwise they will not work as expected.

In order to stack form elements on smaller screens and have (say) two columns (6 grid columns each, really) on bigger resolutions, you need to apply two classes to your cols.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
```

Essentially you're telling bootstrap that from the smallest resolution (xs) on the element should span 12 grid columns, while for small resolutions (sm) on the element should span 6 grid columns.

On [this codepen](http://codepen.io/fredrocha/pen/GWgRJP?editors=1100) I added these classes so you can see the solution at work. Hope it helps.

Comment: So if I rename my main form div to "content center_div", then they would fall in line? I"ll give that a shot, thank you

Comment: @H.Norman I meant .container, not .content, sorry. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! :) Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but one quick issue: This works perfectly where I have two fields in a row, but some rows have three fields. I want those to still have 3 in a row on desktop but then stack on mobile, which falls out of the '6 vs 12' window. Is there a certain way to format that?

Comment: That should be simple, using col-sm-4 for each of the 3 columns. (4 x 3 = 12). [Here](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)'s a great resource that explains the BS grid.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. Thought there was a trick to splitting them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <html>
        <head>
            <title>
            Mobile form responsvie
            </title>
     <style>
  <style>
        .row
        {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        }
        .form-group.col-xs-5 {
        margin-left: 30px;
        }
        .input-inline
        {
        width:50%;
        }
        .input-inline
        {
        width:50%;
        }
       .center_div {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}      
        @media only screen and (max-width: 720px)
        {  
        .input-inline
        {
       
        }
        h3{
            color:grey;
        }
        .form-group.col-xs-5
        {
        margin-left: 0px;
        }
 
       
        .center_div label{
        width:100%;
        float: none;
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
        }
       .buttonolder input {
    margin-left: 18%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
        </style>
</style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
              <div class="center_div">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>First Name</h3>
                        <input  class="input-inline" name="fName" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Last Name</h3>
                        <input  class="input-inline" name="lName" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Company Name</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="compName" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Business Type</h3>
                        <select name="businessNeeds">
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            <option value="IntDesign">Interior Designer</option>
                            <option value="Ecom">E-Commerce Only</option>
                            <option value="Retail">Retail Store Only</option>
                            <option value="RetailEcom">Retail and E-Commerce</option>
                            <option value="Mult">Multiple Locations</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Address</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" class="form-control input-lg"                name="address" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>City</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="city" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>State</h3>
                        <select name="state">
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            /*Took out states for space*/
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Zip</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="zip" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Phone</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="phone" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Email</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" id="email" name="uemail" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Create a Username</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="uname" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Create a Password</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" class="form-control" name="pass" type="password" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" class="form-control"name="ConfPass" type="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Sales Tax ID</h3>
                        <input class="input-inline" name="taxID" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                        <h3>Upload Tax ID Certificate</h3>
                        <input class="upload-file" name="fileUpload" type="file" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="buttonolder">
                        <input class="upload-file" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 21%;margin-top: 3%;text-align: center;padding: 8px;padding-left: 27px;padding-right: 27px;cursor: pointer;">
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```